# Data generation with defined size (byte)

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I generate a dictionary that contains random values with different sizes:  100 bytes, 200 bytes, 1 kbytes, 1 Gbytes, etc., ?

I have already tried with `getsizeof`, but I didn't get what I was expecting.

```
output=[]
var=[]
max=input("bytes size \n")

while ((sys.getsizeof(var))- max)<=0:

    sensor = {
        'dt': time.time(),
        'data': random.randint(10,10),
        'unit': 'Celsius'
    }

    var.append(sensor)

    if ((sys.getsizeof(var))- max)<=0:
        output.append(sensor)

    #print(sys.getsizeof(output))

data=str(output)
jdata=json.dumps(data)
print (jdata)
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Python generally abstracts memory management away so you don't have to worry about it. What did you already try, what were you expecting, and what happened instead?

Comment: [**Edit the question**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30005049/edit). What values, what sizes? How precise does it need to be? Note that if you're using a dictionary the space it reserves for storage will be **doubled** each time it gets ~2/3 (IIRC) full, plus the standard object overhead. An empty dictionary is already `288` bytes, as it has enough space for (again, IIRC) 8 items.

Comment: Again, **how precise does it need to be**? Python is a high-level language, probably not the best choice if you need to be accurate to the byte. Why not just go in rough orders of magnitude? And please **show the code and describe the problem**, within the question itself.

Comment: Oh, for the love of... [**EDIT THE QUESTION!**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30005049/edit) Whitespace matters in Python, so it's even less readable in comments than most other languages. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
import os
import sys
fout = open('output_file', 'wb')
fout.write(os.urandom(1024)) # replace 1024 with size_kb if not unreasonably large
fout.close()
fin = open('output_file', 'rb')
content = fin.read()
print sys.getsizeof(content)-21
# and from here do anything with content
```

**EDIT**

After reading again your question and analyse your code, the code work fine. You wil never get an output with exact size because your size of sensor objects is not multiple of 1.

The previous code create only a dummy data with a specific size